# How to change mouse cursor in Xcode on OS X?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos

I have made a painting program on OS X. When I change to the Brush function, I want the mouse cursor to be changed to a rectangle cursor. The rectangle size would be the brush size. If the brush size is 10px, the mouse cursor would be 10X10px rectangle.

How can I do that by Objective-C? How to draw the cursor and set it? Thanks a lot.

Comment: I just want to change the mouse cursor to a customize shape..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to work with `NSCursor` to create a custom cursor. The cursor needs an `NSImage` as it's look and an `NSPoint` as the cursors hot spot.

The `NSImage` could be loaded from an image or create manually. You can add this in the `viewDidLoad` method of your ViewController. Store the cursor as attribute of that class. It's of course also possible to do this in the `NSView`-Subclass itself (in `awakeFromNib` for example):

```
NSSize cursorSize = NSMakeSize(10, 10);

NSImage *cursorImg = [[NSImage alloc] initWithSize: cursorSize];
// Draw any color on the image
[cursorImg lockFocus];
[[NSColor blackColor] setFill];
[NSBezierPath fillRect:NSMakeRect(0, 0, cursorSize.width, cursorSize.height)];
[cursorImg unlockFocus];
cursor = [[NSCursor alloc] initWithImage:cursorImg hotSpot:NSMakePoint(cursorSize.width/2.0, cursorSize.height/2.0)];

// you now have a cursor. You must set it (e.g. in mouseEntered-method of a view:

[cursor setOnMouseEntered:YES];
[self.view addTrackingRect:self.view.bounds owner:cursor userData:NULL assumeInside:YES];
```

You could change the color and the size of the cursor by adapting the `NSColor` and the `NSSize cursorSize`. Remember to call `removeTrackingRect` on the `NSView` when you're done with the cursor (at latest, when the `NSViewController` is deallocating).

See apple doc for [NSCursor](https://developer.apple.com/Library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSCursor_Class/index.html) for how to work with cursors in Cocoa.

Comment: I have copied this code to into - (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification, but nothing changed. The mouse cursor is normal... Please help

Comment: I think you have to do it in a `mouseEnter`-method of your view.

Comment: I add the method, but when the mouse enter into the window, the mouse cursor will lost and I cannot see the mouse...

Comment: Have you tried moving the mouse? By default, a new cursor is hidden until the mouse moves. Do you get any exceptions?

Comment: Yes, I have tried moving the mouse, but it has been hidden at all. I cannot see it until I click on something on the screen like XCode stop running button or something. If I don't click, it won't show up even if I move it onto Dock bar..

Comment: Okay. I missed some details in my example. I've updated the code with a tested code example. You can change the `[NSColor blackColor]` to any color you like.

Comment: Which part should I add to MouseEntered method? I have tried the code, it still doesn't work..